# Is there a compuer science term for string versions of other (primitive) types?

Tags: terminology, naming

Is there an established term for strings that will be parsed into numbers, booleans, dates, etc?
For example the string "12" is parsed into the integer 12, while "Slartibartfast" is used as a label, as-is.

Comment: Parsable, maybe? I'd be surprised if there's an official term for something like this since usually you're more concerned with whether it can be parsed into a specific type rather than into any non-string at all.

Comment: Possibly related tags: [tag:string-parsing] [tag:types] [tag:type-conversion] [tag:primitive-types]

Comment: "stringly typed" maybe?

Comment: Maybe "string representation"? Or is that more related to output? Maybe this is related to syntax vs semantics - I mean primitives are defined syntactically (e.g. `12` in Python is an int), but a string is parsed semantically (e.g. `int("12")` in Python creates an int from a string primitive).